# SQL Server Agent Job doesn't work for shared drive

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-agent-job, network-drive

SQL Agent History says "To view the details for the execution, right-click on the Integration Services Catalog, and open the [All Executions] report"

When I open the [All Executions] report, this is the full error:

Message Type: OnError
Message: TEST:Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio...\python.exe" "\\Server "B"\r$\...\Scripts\Python\TEST.py" at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio...\DLLs", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

Same error, different path:
Message: TEST:Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio...\python.exe" "\\Server "B"\R\...\Scripts\Python\TEST.py" at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio...\DLLs", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

Server "A"

- Microsoft SQL Server 2019
- SSIS Package named "Test.dtsx" that executes the Python script (test.py) on the mapped drive "R"
- Mapped drive named ("R") that is pointed to the Script folder on Server "B"
- SQL Server Credential made using the AD Service Account
- SQL Server Proxy made and pointed to the AD Service Account Credential, Active for all subsystems
- SSIS Package (Test.dtsx) deployed to the Integration Services Catalogs
- SQL Agent Job references the Integration Services Catalogs Test.dtsx package
- - Owner: AD Service Account | Run as: Proxy

Server "B"

- Microsoft SQL Server 2019
- Script folder in the R drive with a Python script (test.py) that appends the word "Hello World" to a Text file (output.txt) in the same folder as the python script
- AD Service Account has permissions on the R drive (Full control | Read & execute)

Testing done so far:

Run on Server "A"

- SSIS package (Test.dtsx) runs successfully when executed manually in visual studio as the AD Service Account
- SSIS package (Test.dtsx) runs successfully when executed in Integration Services Catalogs as AD Service Account
- SSIS package (Test.dtsx) Fails when executed in SQL Server Agent Jobs | Owner: AD Service Account | Run as: Proxy

Edit:
Just double checked and the entire R drive is Shared on Server "B".
I switch the path in the ssis package to "\server\R..."  that this did not work either.  Is there a difference between sharing a folder vs sharing a drive?

Comment: Don't keep us in suspence, what's the error you're getting? There should be more than just the exit code

Comment: `mapped drive` The account is mapped to a user but likely not a service account. Switch to a UNC path

Comment: Windows drive mappings are per-user.  Switch to a UNC path.

Comment: `\\server\r$` is neither a mapped drive nor a shared folder. It's an attempt to connect to a drive directly as an administrator. Don't do that, it's only meant for administrators. Create a proper shared folder and access it as `\\server\folder_name`

Comment: The agent runs as a specific user account, and that user probably has not been granted permissions to access this server share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched the Agent Job to instead point to the dtsx on the File system.

Reran the Agent Job expecting it to fail, it did.  This time it provided a workable error: "*FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'R:\...\OUTPUT.txt*"

Turns out I had updated the Agent Job and the "*Execute Process Task Editor*" with the UNC path but failed to do so in the python script; the script referenced the OUTPUT.txt file.

Updated the python script with the UNC path and the Agent Job completed successfully.